# spring-cloud-stream-kafka Consume only latest messages after application startup

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

In our project we are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka version 1.1.2 to integrate with kafka. Recently we had a situation where one of our service consumed old messages(already consumed) from a topic after startup. That topic has 2 partitions and 2 consumers grouped under a consumer group. We are not sure whether the offset is committed to zookeeper properly or not. Below error message is thrown for each messages during the startup.

```
[-kafka-listener-2] ERROR o.s.k.listener.LoggingErrorHandler.handle - Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = statemachine_deal_notification, partition = 1, offset = 926, key = null, value = [B@6fab0a32)
```

To make sure this doesn't happen again we always wanted to read only the latest message in the topic. I found setting `resetOffsets` to `true` and `startOffset` to `latest` will do the job. But these properties doesn't impact the consumer. Later found this feature has been dropped.

Is there any other way that we can make sure consumers in a specific group consumes only the latest messages ???.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug and subsequently fixed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/7355ada4613ad50fe95430f1859d4ea65f004be1. You can try out the SNAPSHOT (1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) versions to verify this fix.